# k3s fail to start as daemoan but works when running manually from command line

Tags: k3s

I am trying to install k3s on a redhat operating system, on an EC2 instance (t3.xlarge)

OS version:

```
$ cat /etc/*release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.6 (Ootpa)"
```

I install mysql on the server. These are the installation commands:

```
export K3S_DATASTORE_ENDPOINT='mysql://user:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/db_name'
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - server --node-taint CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoExecute --tls-san locahost
```

However I am getting errors:

```
$ systemctl status k3s.service
● k3s.service - Lightweight Kubernetes
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/k3s.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-09-11 15:03:05 UTC; 5s ago
     Docs: https://k3s.io
  Process: 71759 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -xc ! /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled --quiet nm-cloud-setup.service (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 11 15:03:05 ip-172-31-28-136.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: k3s.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 11 15:03:05 ip-172-31-28-136.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightweight Kubernetes.
Sep 11 15:03:10 ip-172-31-28-136.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: k3s.service: Service RestartSec=5s expired, scheduling restart.
Sep 11 15:03:10 ip-172-31-28-136.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: k3s.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 109.
Sep 11 15:03:10 ip-172-31-28-136.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped Lightweight Kubernetes.
```

However I manage to run manually using:

```
k3s server
```

Which results:

```
$ k3s kubectl get nodes
NAME                                             STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
ip-172-31-28-136.eu-central-1.compute.internal   Ready    control-plane,master   14m   v1.24.4+k3s1
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since you posted this, but I ran into the same issue and it came down to a syntax error in the systemd launch script. If you look at /etc/systemd/system/k3s.service you'll this line:

ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -xc '! /usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled --quiet nm-cloud-setup.service'

The "/bin/sh -xc '!" part was the issue. If you replace that line with this one:

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled --quiet nm-cloud-setup.service

Everything will work as expected.

Comment: Curiously, what does `-xc` do?